# Importing 3D model in C# -opengl

Tags: c#, opengl, model, 3d, blender

i want to know how to import 3d models from Blender into Opengl using C#.net. Blender can export model in Collada, .3ds, Stanford(.ply), .obj, .x3d and .fbx format.
How to use any of the model mention above in C#-opengl. Is there any libraries ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of any libraries, but the `.obj` format is pretty easy to parse if you need to write your own. http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec

Comment: I've written c# mesh readers for wavefront .obj and render .slp. Both are fairly simple to implement. Making them look pretty on the screen is much harder.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you use [SharpGL](http://www.sharpgl.codeplex.com/). **SharpGL** library has inbuilt parsers to import models from other formats (.obj and .3ds). It also has WPF and Windows forms control for rendering 3d models in .NET environment. I am currently using it for exporting a 3d model designed in **Blender** as .**Obj** and importing it into WPF using **SharpGL**. It works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL will not load model for you. Chose the model type then load that model files using a corresponding file loader/parser and feed the extracted data to OpenGL. For eg. your model may be MD2,3ds. If you study the file format specification of model and you are familiar with OpenGL then you can write your own parser.
Here is link for the md2 file format specification http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md2-specs-en.html
Here is link for 3ds file format specification  http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/3DS.spec
you can find other model file format specification in google. Study them and write you own parser.

Comment: easy model is .obj @Chris Sinclair has provide the link in above comment. You can get lots of sample code in c++ in google just convert it in c#.This type of question in here is off topic just write you own parser if you get any problem then ask here.